# Unable to upload build in iTunes when using Google Plus through Pods

Tags: ios, google-plus, app-store-connect

I am using GooglePlus installed from cocoapods in my project. When i trying to upload in iTunes, it always return this error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: you could have easily googled this error message & its fix.

Comment: @SamB Thank you so much.